# Rails 5.1 Bootstrap requires rails-assets.org and rails-assets-thether?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Picking up Rails 5.1 some examples are using rails-assets.org and rails-assets-thether. I am having trouble with that and I am asking whether they are the right way to use Bootstrap with Rails 5.1?

Answer (score 0):

I've used Bootstrap 3 and 4 in several Rails projects, you shouldn't need either Rails-assets or the rails-assets-thether gem.

If you want Bootstrap 4, checkout the new(ish) [bootstrap gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) just throw `gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta2.1'` into your gemfile and also `gem 'jquery-rails'` on which Bootstrap depends.

That should be all you need dependency wise, there is some further configuration but the Bootstrap documentation does a good job walking you through it.

For older bootstrap use [this gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass).

Comment: I realize 3 months on it's likely you've already figured this out and moved on but I'm answering for the record and to take this out of unanswered.